# Friedel-Crafts acylation with withdrawing group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acylation

Will a Friedel- Crafts acylation take place on ortho-bromotoluene? I do understand that Friedel Crafts reaction does not occur when there is an electron withdrawing group on the ring but is there any exception when it comes to ortho-bromotoluene? Please do help me understand this concept

Comment: Bromine is not very electron withdrawing, methyl is electron-donating, the two effect approximately cancel out so F-C will work on bromotoluene.

Comment: It will occur. Particularly favorable at the para location w.r.t to methyl group.